# BottomNavigationView does not highlight custom icon

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I want to implement a `BottomNavigationView` and have added one of material.io's icons as a png to my drawables. When I insert it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

<!-- This is my item added to the normal template -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_more" />

</menu>
```

And use it in the main activity, It shows up, but the item will not highlight when pressed on the simulator, whereas the others will ( by highlight, I mean it will slightly blow up and change to the primary color, showing some text underneath). I tried both vectors and .pngs, nothing will work. I am running backwards compatible to Android 5.0 (Target Version 27).

The home Activity currently looks like:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private TextView mTextMessage;

  private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
  mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.navigation_home:
              mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
              return true;
          case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
              mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
              return true;
          case R.id.navigation_notifications:
              mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
              return true;
          case R.id.navigation_more:
              mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_more);
      }
      return false;
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

      mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
      BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

}
```

The text view is set correctly, the icon just won't highlight.

Comment: your navigation method always return false, try return true when there is a case handled by the switch

Comment: Yup! And I was pondering over this for about one day...

Comment: awesome, iv'e added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your navigation method always return false, try return true when there is a case handled by the switch ;)

for example:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
            mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
            mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_more:
            mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_more);
            return true; // this was my mistake...
        default: 
            return false;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not the code I used, since you would fall through to default if you did it like this (you never break...). Instead, return true after each case and get out of the switch. If no case applies, return false. I edited your answer to what worked for me.